# How to properly remove all extra spaces and signs from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried this function to remove all signs and extra spaces from string and return a pure string of words:

```js
function simplify(string) {

    return string.toLowerCase()
    
    .replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\.|\*|\/|\//g,'')
    .trim().replace(/\n/g, " ")

}


const string = "   this    is  !   *     ? ear :: ! ?  *****  ";

console.log(simplify(string))
```

As you see there are still extra spaces.

The desired result would be :

> "this is ear"

How to achieve this in the most efficient way (in case of **performance** not simplicity of the code)

Comment: You have not remove _any_ spaces at all yet, your regex doesn't care about space characters at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well your current pattern does not even include anything to cover whitespace.  I would use this version:

```js
var string = "   this    is  !   *     ? ear :: ! ?  *****  ";
var output = string.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, " ").trim();
console.log(output);
```

Here we are simply removing groups of 1 or more non letter/number characters, and then replacing with a single space.  There is an edge case here which may result in a single extra space appearing at the very start or end of the string, so we make a call to `trim()` to clean this up.

Comment: There is one usual caveat: it will remove the letters in some languages like Russian or Polish. If it is not a problem, the `/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g` will do.

Comment: @SaraRee ... for solving the issue mentioned by *Wiktor* have a look into *Unicode Property Escapes* e.g at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) or at [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode#unicode-properties-p). The regex comparison just visualizes it ... [`/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/8RtJCr/1) versus [`/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/8RtJCr/2).